# How to extract a substring from a URL in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following string

```
git@bitbucket.org:user/my-repo-name.git
```

I want to extract this part

```
my-repo-name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash:

```
s='git@bitbucket.org:user/my-repo-name.git'
[[ $s =~ ^.*/(.*)\.git$ ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Output:

```
my-repo-name
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method, using bash's [variable substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
s='git@bitbucket.org:user/my-repo-name.git'
s1=${s#*/}
echo ${s1%.git}
```

Output:

```
my-repo-name
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to combine the `#` and `%` operators into a single substitution.

Comment: Parameter expansions cannot, unfortunately, be nested in `bash`. (`zsh` would allow the nesting `${${s#*/}%.git}`, as well as a simpler `$s:t:r`.)